# python plotly - show label on selected nodes

Tags: plotly, label, nodes, selected

I use plotly to plot a network as in the figure. I need to select "top" nodes based on their size and their networks. In this example, nodes 1,2,3 should be selected, despite the fact that node 4 is bigger than nodes 2,3; because in that cluster node 1 has been selected as the biggest one. Then I want to show label for nodes 1,2,3.

How to show labels of such nodes?

I know that hover can show label, but only for 1 node and disappear when mouse moves away.
I did a trick to plot labels for nodes in a subset of all nodes - however, selecting by code does not allow to correctly identify the "top" nodes 1,2,3 as I want like above (if I select the 3 biggest nodes, it gives 1,4,2).
[image];

Comment: I know how to manually select some nodes on the figure, but don't know what to do with that

Comment: The reply in this thread using Dash can be accepted as solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70173061/display-hover-when-clicked-instead-of-hovering-over-a-datapoint-in-plotly-python

Comment: can you include the code you used to produce your figure? that would make it much easier for us to help you out – thanks!